# How to get all decimal digits provided in a json response in Postman?

Tags: decimal, postman, postman-collection-runner

I Have an API that returns the following (example):

```
{"rate": 3.568640920671274015}
```

In the Tests space, I try to retrieve the rate value:

```
pm.test("Set variables", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.environment.set('new-rate', jsonData.rate);
```

But as result, I get only:

```
3.568640920671274
```

It seems that Postman is truncating the result. Is there a way to avoid that?

PS: The value came from a decimal. (inside de API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing something like this:

```
pm.environment.set('new-rate', jsonData.rate.toPrecision(18));
```

worked to me.